# jxls file generation hangs for ever when rows > 10,000

Tags: java, performance, jxls

I have a excel report that gets generated.  Most of the time, it works fine when rows are up to about 2,000.

This morning, I tried to generate a report that has 11,000 rows and could not figure out why it would just hang since it was following the same unchanged code - see below.  I still can't figure it out besides the fact that XLSTransformer could be really slow?

```
List<Map<String, Object>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> sheetData = null;
    for(EntityForecastWrapper wrapper : wrappers) {
        sheetName = Integer.toString(wrapper.getEntityId());
        sheetNames.add(sheetName);
        sheetData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        sheetData.put("wrapper", wrapper);
        maps.add(sheetData);
    }
    Map<String, Object> beansMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Workbook workbook = null;
    XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
    try {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error("generating excel");
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(getReportTemplate().getLabel());
        workbook = transformer.transformMultipleSheetsList(is, maps, sheetNames, "map", beansMap, 0);
        Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error("generated excel");
        /*FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();*/
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error("Error writing excel data: ", e);
    }
```

The code basically never comes back from line:

```
workbook = transformer.transformMultipleSheetsList(is, maps, sheetNames, "map", beansMap, 0);
```

It is very fast when the row count is not huge (eg 500 to 1000 rows).  The row content never changes, same # of columns...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Jxls tries to build the whole document in RAM at once. I had a quick flip over the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jxls/jxls-core/0.9.9/net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer.java) and saw, that jxls uses the POI HSSFWorkbook internally - no streams to help the processing of huge amount of data.

A solution that might work is to process the data in smaller parts (in my case ~1000 Entries) and save the output of jxls temporary on the file system. After all data is processed, merge the files using poi. Not a very pretty solution...

Answer (score 1):

In our case this happens when the JXLS template uses [dynamic columns](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/dynamiccolumnssample.html) or other tags. When we have a simple template just with `${name}` property access then it runs fast. We have switched to direct POI API for more complicated reports.

Update: also processing of XLSX templates consumes much more memory and time then XLS templates.

Answer (score 0):

We did many tests with Jxls XLS Transformer and some comparison with Jett XLS Transformer.

Jxls transformer (ver. 2.6.0):

- Very quick in simple generation to XLS (about 1.5-2 times faster than Jett), when everything is prepared (no any formatting or formulas, only simple text) e.g. 12000 rows takes 2 sec.
- Very very slow (performance leak) generation to XLSX. About **1000 times** (sic!) slower, than generating to XLS, e.g. 12000 rows takes 30 min.
- Template has limited capabilities, something not working well or there is no good explanation, how to use it

Jett transformer (0.11.0 beta):

- Quick in simple generation to XLS (about 1.5-2 times slower than Jxls), when everything is prepared (no any formatting or formulas, only simple text) e.g. 12000 rows takes 4 sec.
- Slower generation to XLSX. About 10 times slower, than generating to XLS, e.g. 12000 rows takes 40 sec.
- Template has simpler syntax, and more capabilities (not tested)